# SetTabListener method error

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, listener

I'm new to android, I'm trying to implement a tabbed actionbar appcompat v7 using the library. 
I have problems setTabListener method. 
this is the code

main activity

```
package net.sgoliver.android.actionbartabs;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Obtenemos una referencia a la actionbar
         final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();

        //Establecemos el modo de navegación por pestañas
        abar.setNavigationMode(
                ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //Ocultamos el título de la actividad
        //abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //Creamos las pestañas
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = 
                abar.newTab().setText("Tab 1");

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 =  
                abar.newTab().setText("tab2");

        //Creamos los fragments de cada pestaña
        Fragment tab1frag = new Tab1Fragment();
        Fragment tab2frag = new Tab2Fragment();


        //Asociamos los listener a las pestañas
        tab1.setTabListener(new MiTabListener(tab1frag));
        tab2.setTabListener(new MiTabListener(tab2frag));

        //Añadimos las pestañas a la action bar
        abar.addTab(tab1);
        abar.addTab(tab2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_new:
                Log.i("ActionBar", "Nuevo!");
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_save:
                Log.i("ActionBar", "Guardar!");;
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_settings:
                Log.i("ActionBar", "Settings!");;
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

and MiTabListener class

```
package net.sgoliver.android.actionbartabs;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class MiTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public MiTabListener(Fragment fg)
    {
        this.fragment = fg;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("ActionBar", tab.getText() + " reseleccionada.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("ActionBar", tab.getText() + " seleccionada.");
        ft.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("ActionBar", tab.getText() + " deseleccionada.");
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

and this is the problem that i have

"The method setTabListener(ActionBar.TabListener) in the type ActionBar.Tab is not applicable for the arguments (MiTabListener)"

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the imports. In your listener they are not from the support library.

Comment: mmmm i don understand, u are talking about the MiTabListener Imports ?